# How to monitor gradients of theano shared variables

Tags: theano

How can one get the values of gradients of theano shared variables ? That is,
how make a `theano.function( outputs=TT.grad( shared vars ))` ?

Take the Minimal Training Example in
[Marek Rei's theano tutorial](http://www.marekrei.com/blog/theano-tutorial):

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as TT
import numpy as np

floatx = theano.config.floatX

#...............................................................................
x = TT.fvector('x')
target = TT.fscalar('target')
W = theano.shared(np.asarray([0.2, 0.7]), 'W')  # state
y = (x * W).sum()
cost = TT.sqr(target - y)
gradients = TT.grad(cost, [W])
W_updated = W - (0.1 * gradients[0])
updates = [(W, W_updated)]
f = theano.function([x, target], y, updates=updates)

x0 = np.array( [1.0, 1.0] ).astype(floatx)
target0 = 20.0

for i in xrange(10):
    output = f( x0, target0 )
    Wval = W.get_value().astype(floatx)
    grad = gradf( x0, Wval, target0 )[0]  # <--- how to define gradf ?
    print "f %-8.3g  W %s  grad %s" % (
            output, Wval, grad )

>>>
f 0.9       W [4.02 4.52]  grad [-22.9 -22.9]
f 8.54      W [6.31 6.81]  grad [-13.8 -13.8]
...
```

One cannot directly

```
gradf = theano.function( [x, W, target], TT.grad(...) )
```

because `theano.function` says

> inputs : list of either Variable or In instances.
>       Function parameters, these are not allowed to be shared variables.

One *could* make a copy of the whole symbolic graph

```
gradients = TT.grad(cost, [W])
```

with inputs Variables, not shared; must be a better way,
perhaps with `givens=` ?

Related:
[[Theano]How to evaluate gradient based on shared variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37857771/theanohow-to-evaluate-gradient-based-on-shared-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't pass `W` as the input argument:

```
gradf = theano.function( [x, target], TT.grad(...) )
```

It will just use the current value of `W`.
It is more challenging if you want it to compute the gradient for some other value of `W`, different from its current value, but it seems like it's not what you want.

Comment: Right, thanks. For gradf at anotherW one could `Wsave = W.get_value(); W.set_value( anotherW ); g = gradf(...); W.set_value( Wsave )` ? seems convoluted.